# How to extract substring from a string in perl after matching certain substring

Tags: perl, substring

I want to extract substring from following string after the Word "Device description" till Symbol "]". Substring length may vary.
Is it possible to do it extract function.?

```
UC_CALLMANAGER [Device name abcde][Device IP address 1.1.1.1][Protocol SIP][Device type 550][Device description 9580 - Cordless][Reason Code 13][IPAddressAttributes 0][UNKNOWN_PARAMNAME:LastSignalRecei
```

Answer (score 3):

If the format of the string is going to same each time but the values only change you can try this

```
cat stck1.txt | awk '{print $12}'
```

where stck1.txt contains your string.

i have modified my command you can try this also which is more dynamic

```
cat stck1.txt | sed 's/.*\[Device description //' | awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 2):

This works, but is probably not the most optimal way.

```
my $string = "UC_CALLMANAGER [Device name abcde][Device IP address 1.1.1.1][Protocol SIP][Device type 550][Device description 9580 - Cordless][Reason Code 13][IPAddressAttributes 0][UNKNOWN_PARAMNAME:LastSignalRecei";

my ($substr) = $string =~ /(?<=Device description )([^\]]+)/g;

print $substr;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if(/Device description ([^\]]*)\]/)' your_file
```

Tested [here](http://ideone.com/ZPPTpK).
Want to put it inside a script?

```
$_=~m/Device description ([^\]]*)\]/g;
my $info=$1;
# $info has the required informatio0n now!
```

Answer (score 0):

This might b helpful and little hit and trial with referenced link example will serve ur purpose,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
  use strict;
  use warnings;

  # Find the location of the substring 'people'

  my $string = 'UC_CALLMANAGER [Device name abcde][Device IP address 1.1.1.1][Protocol SIP][Device type 550][Device description 9580 - Cordless][Reason Code 13][IPAddressAttributes 0][UNKNOWN_PARAMNAME:LastSignalRecei';
  my $fragment =  substr $string, index($string, 'Device description');

  my $limit = substr $fragment index($fragment, ']');

  print "  string: <$string>\n";
  print "fragment: <$fragment>\n";

  print " FINAL OUTPUT : <$limit>\n";
```

> **Output :**
>
> ***String :*** UC_CALLMANAGER [Device name abcde][Device IP address
>   1.1.1.1][Protocol SIP][Device type 550][Device description 9580 - Cordless][Reason Code 13][IPAddressAttributes
>   0][UNKNOWN_PARAMNAME:LastSignalRecei
>
> ***Fragment :*** Device description 9580 - Cordless][Reason Code
>   13][IPAddressAttributes 0][UNKNOWN_PARAMNAME:LastSignalRecei
>
> ***FINAL OUTPUT*** : Device description 9580 - Cordless

For detailed information please look : [referenced with diff examples](http://perlmeme.org/howtos/perlfunc/substr.html)

Comment: `my $size = length('Device description '); my $fragment =  substr $string, index($string, 'Device description ') + $size, index($string, ']') - $size;` I believe he wants this part only.